# How can I switch a subversion repository using only command-line tools?

Tags: svn

Until recently I was a read-only user of an open-source project on GoogleCode. I've been invited onto the team however I need to switch my local repository from using the http:// url to the more secure https:// url which will allow me to commit.

At work TortoiseSVN for Windows has a handy "switch" feature which will allow me to change the server for any local repo, however this feature does not seem to be present in the SVN for eclipse & command line that I have on my Ubuntu 9.04 desktop. Surely there must be a way to do it?

As an act of desperation I could simply extract the diff to text, check out the new repo from fresh and then re-apply my diffs... but there has to be a more elegant way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The command-line way is:

```
svn switch --relocate http://old-url https://new-url
```